# Scientific display alignment problem in pgfplotstable environment

Tags: pgfplots, vertical-alignment, siunitx, pgfplotstable

the following TeX piece generates relatively good looking table. However, there are two issues with it.

If I change any of the 6 in the 3rd column, e.g. to `\SI{12.1e4}`, it gives error. The only way to fix the error is to put another text character such as `\` after  `\SI{12.1e4}`.

And there is an alignment problem (unintended indentation) with `1.4`.
I need to create lots of these type of graphs in my thesis and really need a uniform/better solution that I missed for the same code piece.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % Formula subscripts using \ce{}    

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl, array}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\definecolor{rulecolor}{RGB}{0,71,171}
\definecolor{tableheadcolor}{gray}{0.92}    

\newcommand*\mycommand[1]{\texttt{\emph{#1}}}    

\newcommand{\topline}{ %
        \arrayrulecolor{rulecolor}\specialrule{0.1em}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}%
        \arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
        \arrayrulecolor{rulecolor}}
% Command \midline consists of 3 rules (top colour tableheadcolor, middle colour black, bottom colour white)
\newcommand{\midtopline}{ %
        \arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\aboverulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
        \arrayrulecolor{rulecolor}\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}%
        \arrayrulecolor{white}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
        \arrayrulecolor{rulecolor}}
% Command \bottomline consists of 2 rules (top colour
\newcommand{\bottomline}{ %
        \arrayrulecolor{white}\specialrule{\aboverulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
        \arrayrulecolor{rulecolor} %
        \specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{\belowbottomsep}}%    


\newcommand{\midheader}[2]{%
        \midrule\topmidheader{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\topmidheader[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{\textsc{#2}}\\%
                \addlinespace[0.5ex]}    

\pgfplotstableset{normal/.style ={%
        header=true,
        string type,
        font=\addfontfeature{Numbers={Monospaced}}\small,
        column type=l,
        every odd row/.style={
            before row=
        },
        every head row/.style={
            before row={\topline\rowcolor{tableheadcolor}},
            after row={\midtopline}
        },
        every last row/.style={
            after row=\bottomline
        },
        col sep=&,
        row sep=\\
    }
}    


\begin{document}    

   \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Thermal and electrical properties of materials[NOT COMPLETE].}
        \pgfplotstabletypeset[normal,
                columns/eg/.style={
                column name={k (\SI{}{\watt\per\meter\per\kelvin})},
                dec sep align},
                columns/mn/.style={
                column name={C (\SI{}{\joule\per\meter\squared\per\kelvin})}},
                columns/ma/.style={
                column type= {p {3cm} },
                column name={Material}},
                columns/au/.style={
                column name={$\sigma$ (\SI{}{\per\ohm\per\meter})}}
        ]{ %
        ma         &  eg  & au & mn \\
        \topmidheader{5}{GST}
        Amorph                    & 0.17 & 3 & 6 \\
        Crystalline              & 0.5 & 2770 & 6 \\
        \midheader{5}{Other Compounds}
        Aluminum          & 25.0 & \SI{37e6} &  \SI{2.15e6} \   \\
        Titanium          & 17.0 & \SI{1.12e5} & \SI{2325e6} \ \\
        Silicon Dioxide   & 1.40 & \SI{1e-16} & \SI{2525e6} \ \\
        }
\end{table}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are various things here which could be altered (improved),  but before addressing them I wonder what you are after in terms of alignment. With columns containing values of for example `3`, `2770` and `1.12e6`, it's hard to have a 'useful' alignment. I'd probably just go for a simple `r` column: would that be OK? I'd certainly consider not aligning exponents: again, would this be OK?

Comment: I don't know about `r` alignment, sorry. And yes, you're right I don't consider aligning exponents. The most noticeable alignment problem -at least to my eye- is `1.4` in the first column. I would rather want they are vertically aligned..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would be wary of trying to do too much alignment here: you have a series of numbers which are not readily compared, so any alignment does not actually contribute to understanding the values. I'm also not sure why you've gone for `pgfplotstable`, which is probably at its best when reading data from external sources.

I'd therefore go for a simple table using `l` and `r` columns, with `\num` from `siunitx` to auto-convert exponent input into the correct form. Something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \sisetup{table-align-exponent = false}
  \begin{tabular}
    {
      @{}
      l
      >{$}r<{$}
      >{$}r<{$}
      >{$}r<{$}
      @{}
    }
    \toprule
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$k$ (\si{\watt\per\metre\per\kelvin})}
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\sigma$ (\si{\per\ohm\per\metre})}
      & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{$C$ (\si{\joule\per\metre\squared\per\kelvin})} \\
    \midrule
    Amorph GST & 0.17 & 3 & 6 \\
    Crystalline GST & 0.5 & 2770 & 6 \\[1em]
    Aluminum & 25 & \num{37e6} & \num{2.15e6} \\
    Titanium & 17 & \num{1.12e5} & \num{2325e6} \\
    Silicon dioxide & 1.4 & \num{1e-16} & \num{2525e6} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

would be my approach, though one can of course add in the additional formatting you have in the question. (Like the author of `booktabs`, I'd favour 'light-weight' formatting of tables.)

Note that `\SI` needs *two* arguments: a number and a unit. You therefore want `\si` for units alone and `\num` for numbers alone. Probably some stray input is being picked up in the example from the question.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph this certainly helps. I agree with you on less alignment may be better in my case. I used `pgfplotstable` since this particular additional formatting I came across with seems fitted with my thesis. And now it is hard to rewrite it for me with `l` and `r` columns. If you're familiar with formatting, can you help me fix moving `25` and `17` , one space right?